# Java's waitFor() method seems to hang

Tags: c#, java

I have written a simple routine in .Net that I need to call from Java and check the exit value. For some reason when called from Java, waitFor never ends. This is in spite of the fact that when called from command prompt .Net routine ends quickly and when called from test.bat it properly returns -1. Anyone has any idea what the problem is?

Here is Java code:

```
public static int runOnceWait(String[] cmdarray) throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
    Process p;
    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdarray);
    int res = p.waitFor();
    p.destroy();
    return res;
}

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws InterruptedException 
 * @throws IOException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
    String [] cmd = new String[2];
    cmd[0]=signer;
    cmd[1]=fileLocation;
    System.out.println ("\"" + cmd[0] + "\" \"" + cmd[1] + "\"");
    System.out.println (runOnceWait(cmd));
}
```

Here's C# code:

```
    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length != 1 && args.Length != 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Use: ");
            Console.WriteLine("DocumentSigner.exe source");
            Console.WriteLine(" or");
            Console.WriteLine("DocumentSigner.exe source, destination");
            return -100;
        }

        string destination = null;

        try
        {
            if (args.Length == 1) destination = Sign(args[0]);
            else destination = Sign(args[0], args[1]);
            Console.WriteLine("Document signed and saved as " + destination);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            return -1;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

For testing purposes I even wrote a .bat file which behaves as expected, i.e. returns ERRORLEVEL of -1.

Here's .bat file:

```
@echo off
rem test.bat
"DocumentSigner.exe" "{5E3C1967-A26E-4FC5-A6A8-3F358F388A3D}.pdf"
@if "%ERRORLEVEL%" == "0" goto good

:fail
    echo Execution Failed
    echo return value = %ERRORLEVEL%
    goto end

:good
    echo Execution succeeded
    echo Return value = %ERRORLEVEL%
    goto end

:end
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: What do you mean by _hang_. `waitFor()` waits for the process to end.

Comment: Sorry. I've edited the question. Basically .Net routine ends quickly and returns -1 when called from command prompt, but Java for some reason thinks it's still running. I have no idea why this is happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the API reference of [java.lang.Process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) (emphasis mine):

> By default, the created subprocess does not have its own terminal or
>   console. All its standard I/O (i.e. stdin, stdout, stderr) operations
>   will be redirected to the parent process, where they can be accessed
>   via the streams obtained using the methods getOutputStream(),
>   getInputStream(), and getErrorStream(). The parent process uses these
>   streams to feed input to and get output from the subprocess. **Because
>   some native platforms only provide limited buffer size for standard
>   input and output streams, failure to promptly write the input stream
>   or read the output stream of the subprocess may cause the subprocess
>   to block, or even deadlock**.

I would try to read from java what your c# application is writing with `Console.WriteLine()`, e.g. doing something like this after your `exec()`

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(  
                    new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));  
String line = null;  
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {  
    System.out.println(line);  
}
```

Comment: Bloody heck, this is it!! But this raises a new question, how should I call processes which might write something on stdout and stderr when I know I won't need them? What is the proper way to dispose of these streams? (That is in regards of making sure the disposition will neither raise nor swallow any exceptions.)

Comment: @ADSMarko I guess the bottom line is that if you run a Process this way, you should always read what that process may be writing on its stdout and stderr, and discard it if you don't care (although I think it may be wiser not to ignore at least stderr)